# Spring SecurityContextHolder is null with AWS Alias

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services

I have a website up on AWS with a hosted zone that does not include the www prefix (http://example.com).  I've also included in the hosted zone an alias with the prefix www (http://www.example.com).

I can access the site from both the non-www and the www prefixed urls.  When I access the site with the non-www url my SecurityContextHolder contains the principal and authorities as expected.

However when I access the site from the www-prefixed url the SecurityContextHolder returns no principal or authorities objects.

I've attempted to use an nginx redirect, however this does not work.  When the following is added there is no external access to the site.

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

What is the best way to get my SecurityContextHolder to return a valid SecurityContext when navigating to the site with the www-prefixed url?

Comment: What r u using for session tracking? Cookies? What is your app server? Tomcat? Looks like cookies domain problem..

Comment: The session is tracked by cookies, the server is tomcat.  I didn't think to check the cookies domain path.  I think you're right!  I'll give that a shot.

Comment: If I'm right I guess you'll have to set domain for session cookie manually. As far as I remember it would be ".example.com" in your case (with dot at the start)

Comment: Well, that didn't quite workout.  The cookie shows:
fbm_778787925616834, base_domain=.example.com, .example.com

Comment: Thats odd.. So, no changes in the app behavior?